# Can't install firebase-tools on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: firebase, ubuntu-16.04

i'm trying to install firebase-tools in ubuntu (16.04) but i get an error

after i execute the command line:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

The error:

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/rezk/.npm/firebase-tools/3.2.1/package.tgz
```

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "firebase-tools"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/rezk/npm-debug.log

how could i solve that?
Note: i have installed Node.js

Answer (score 2):

i think it just about using `sudo` before the command line:

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

thank you!

Comment: FYI, installing npm packages with sudo can sometimes lead to pain. There are alternatives: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

Comment: @cartant could you explain why? I just install the new version of firebase-tools with sudo on my ubuntu 14.04 and I'm now I can't deploy on local... I don't know If I need to unistall and install it again

Comment: @Jaco Using sudo can effect significant permissions problems. It's a mistake I made once and never again. Read the link which itself has a link to an npm article (at the bottom) that might help explain the problem.